# What do 'T and 'U mean in F#?

Tags: f#

Such as in the http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370378.aspx example `List.map : ('T -> 'U) -> 'T list -> 'U list` .

Sorry if this sounds simplistic, but Googling it turns up no explanations.

Thanks!

Comment: They can be any type, its called generics

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case `'T` and `'U` are arbitrary types.

In other cases, restrictions might be placed on `'t` using constraints.

Occasionally the names may be descriptive like `'key` or `'value`.  In F#, the key is that a `'` before a type makes it generic.

Similarly, types may be prefixed with a `#` which allows for any type which can be upcast to the given type.

More complex type constraints using inline methods can be used with a `^` before the type name  allowing for member constraints which are not possible using the .Net type system and will only work with F# inline functions.

Comment: Sorry I just missed your post, John. In that case, what is the difference between 'T and 'U? And why not use 'a ?

Comment: `'T` and `'U` are (not necersarrily) different generic types.  The choice to use `t` instead of `'a` is arbitrary.

Comment: Do you mean that 'T can be any generic type, 'U can be any generic type, and we just use 'T and 'U to mean any two potentially different generic types?

Comment: @JohnPalmer, did you mean *upcast* ?

Answer (score 3):

From the specifications:

A type of the form 'ident is a variable type. For example, the following are all variable types:

```
'a
'T
'Key
```

And for your question on why `'T` and not `'a`:

> Note: this specification generally uses uppercase identifiers such as
>   'T or 'Key for user-declared generic type parameters, and uses
>   lowercase identifiers such as 'a or 'b for compiler-inferred generic
>   parameters.

http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html

In this case, all it means is `List.map : ('T -> 'U) -> 'T list -> 'U list` takes in a function that converts `'T` type value to `'U` type, a list of 'T type values and returns a list of ''U' type values - which is, of course, what a map does.